# ConditionalPanel doesn't support variables with dot in the name, any work around?

Tags: r, shiny

This would work

```
  checkboxInput("test", "test", TRUE),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition="input.test",
    h2("test test")

  ),
```

but this not

```
  checkboxInput("tes.t", "tes.t", TRUE),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition="input.tes.t",
    h2("tes.t tes.t")

  ),
```

Where in the document does it say the name with dots are not supported? Are there any work around so I don't have to change my variable names?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `conditionalPanel` the condition is a Javascript expression. You are relying on Javascript's dot notation when you type "input.test".

You don't have to change your variable names. There is a simple workaround, just use the square bracket notation instead: `input["tes.t"]`

```
 checkboxInput("tes.t", label="tes.t", TRUE),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition='input["tes.t"]',
      h2("tes.t tes.t")
```

will work.